# Проблема с делегатом в DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net

Возникла непонятная ситуация при удалении данных их dataGridView

```
if (dataGridView4.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    this.Invoke(new Action(() => dataGridView4.Rows.Clear()));
}
for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
{
    this.Invoke(new Action(() => dataGridView4.Rows.Add()));
    this.Invoke(new Action(() => dataGridView4.Rows[0].Visible = false));
    this.Invoke(new Action(() => dataGridView4.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = imageList2.Images[39]));
}
```

при попытки добавить их снова выдает сообщение на

```
this.Invoke(new Action(() => dataGridView4.Rows.Add()));
```

> Object reference not set to an instance of the object

а если сделать так

```
this.Invoke(new Action(() => listBox1.Items.Clear()));
if (dataGridView4.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView4.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action(() => dataGridView4.Rows.RemoveAt(i)));
    }
    //this.Invoke(new Action(() => dataGridView4.Rows.Clear()));
}
for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
{
    this.Invoke(new Action(() => dataGridView4.Rows.Add()));
    this.Invoke(new Action(() => dataGridView4.Rows[0].Visible = false));
    this.Invoke(new Action(() => dataGridView4.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = imageList2.Images[39]));
}
```

то он удаляет только часть данных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте написать так:

```
public static class DataGridViewEx 
{
    public static void ClearRows(this DataGridView dataGridView)
    {
        if (dataGridView.DataSource != null)
        {
            dataGridView.DataSource = null;
        }
        else
        {
            dataGridView.Rows.Clear();
        }
        dataGridView.Refresh();
     }
}
```

Вызываем:

```
dataGridView4.ClearRows();
```

Answer (score 2):

Заменить:

```
for (int i = 1; i < dataGridView4.Rows.Count; i++){
        this.Invoke(new Action(() => dataGridView4.Rows.RemoveAt(i)));
    }
```

на

```
for (int i = dataGridView4.Rows.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i){
        this.Invoke(new Action(() => dataGridView4.Rows.RemoveAt(i)));
    }
```

Проблему легко можно понять, если самому вручную на бумажке прогнать ваш цикл.

Прогоним по шагам:

1. i = 1; Count, предположим 5. 1 < 5; Удаляем 1 элемент.
2. i = 2; Count = 4; 2 < 4, Удаляем 2 элемент.
3. i = 3; Count = 3; 3 = 3; Ничего не удаляем.

В итоге удалился 1 и 3 элемент. Вы можете спросить: "Почему 3 элемент?". Потому что на 1 шаге мы удалили элемент, поэтому на 2 шаге при удалении 2 элемента (удаление то уже из нового массива строк), по факту удаляется 3 элемент изначального массива строк.

Comment: Да, эту ошибку я уже заметил, но мне хочется воспользоваться  dataGridView4.Rows.Clear()